# BASH | get text between brackets

Tags: string, bash, output

could you please help me with my problem to get number from input?

I have input something like this:

```
Good [AA0060]    [LIB1:    61]        No   02/11/15 08:38:46
```

and I would like to get number after LIB1:

```
61
```

Problem is that I can get also input like this:

```
Good [AA0060]  AA0060  [LIB1:    61]        No   02/11/15 08:38:46
```

UPDATE: LIB1 should be variable. I would like have it more dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `sed` command.

```
 sed 's/.*\[LIB1: \{0,\}\(.*\)\].*/\1/'  file_name
```

Using the variable,

Consider,

```
 match="LIB1"

 sed 's/.*\['$match': \{0,\}\(.*\)\].*/\1/' file_name
```

Comment: How to get there variable instead of LIB1? It should be more dynamic.

Comment: @ Karthikeyan.R.S ,Remove unwanted grouping `sed 's/.*\[LIB1: \{0,\}\(.*\)\].*/\1/' FileName`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this `awk` command

```
awk  -FLIB1: '{print $2--}' FileName
```

or

```
awk  -FLIB1: '{print $2+0}' FileName
```

**Example :**

```
echo "Good [AA0060]  AA0060  [LIB1:    61]        No   02/11/15 08:38:46" | awk  -FLIB1: '{print $2--}'
```

**Output :**

```
61
```

Comment: Prefer: `print $2+0` instead, +1 for the approach

Answer (score 0):

use this `perl` command:

```
perl -lne 'print $1 if(/LIB1:\s+(\d+)\]/)' file
```

Comment: Output from perl contains also empty characters before number.